# Determining an equation for parabolic graphs

Tags: functions

Given only the vertex of the graph, how do I find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts to finally get an equation in the form of $y= a(x+p)^2 + q$?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Please expand on your question. What do you know about parabolas so far? What are you stuck on? Also here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Comment: You only have 1 point and 1 slope (=0, at vertex) still lack 1 condition to define a parabola.

Comment: The vertex will give you what line the parabola is symmetric about, but that will give you at best a set of solutions. You need one additional constraint to tell exactly what the roots are. Intuitively, it would suffice to know how "skinny" or "wide" the parabola is.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible, e.g for vertex $(0,0)$ you have $\infty$ possibilities:

- $y=x^2$;
- $y=3x^2$;
- $y=-x^2$.

And any other $y=ax^2$ will do.

Answer (score 0):

Using the vertex (c,d)

You get $a(x-c)^2+d$

To check just substitute the $x=c$ and get the output $y=d$. Now you can choose any value of $a$ except zero which turns the parabola into line $y=0$.

One example is if the vertex is $(2,3)$. You should get $a(x-2)^2+3$. Now pick any value of $a$ except zero.